# Existe alguma forma de gerar migrations baseando num banco de dados existente em Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Quando usei o Django do Python, me surpreendi com o comando `inspectdb`, que é capaz de gerar os models baseando-se numa banco de dados já existente.

No Laravel, temos as migrations para poder trabalhar com o banco de dados, e acho uma maneira bem limpa e organizada de manter as alterações do banco de um projeto.

Acontece porém que, no Laravel, por padrão, as migrations sempre são criadas manualmente, e geralmente os tutoriais que vejo sempre indica que elas devem ser usado desde o início do desenvolvimento do projeto.

Me surgiu, porém, uma nova necessidade: Tenho um dump de um banco de dados e gostaria de transformá-lo em migrations do Laravel.

Existe alguma biblioteca no Laravel que possibilite engenharia reversa de um banco de dados, transformando-o em migrations do próprio Laravel?

Ou seja, quero que uma biblioteca leia o banco existente e gere as migrations baseado nessa estrutura.

Gostaria de uma resposta para isso, se possível, para Laravel 4 e 5 (pois uso o 4 ainda).

**Observação**: Eu não gostaria de soluções como importar o DUMP pra migration e executá-lo. Não é o ideal para o caso que eu preciso.

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma biblioteca chamada [Migrations Generator](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator) que lê um banco de dados existente e gera as `migrations` correspondentes e ela inclusive dá suporte ao Laravel 4.

Eu fiz um teste simples usando Laravel 5.6, com o banco no Mariadb e ele gerou corretamente todas as colunas de cada tabela, só que há um porem. Eu percebi que relações não foram geradas.

De qualquer forma, vale a pena olhar e testar.

Comment: Eu usei uma que lê os relacionamentos.

Comment: Eu dei uma pesquisada afundo pelo que percebi ele gerou as relações só que num arquivo separado. De qualquer forma, essa biblioteca é uma boa opção. Qual você utilizou ?

Comment: Ah, interessante. Eu tinha usado uma `barryvdh/migration-generator`, mas percebi que ` xethron/migrations-generator` atendeu.